# How to pass multivalue data to a choropleth in dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js

I'm working on a crossfilter between a line chart and choropleth. I recently got a much better understanding of the reduce method in dc.js, so I want to pass through some more metadata about each data point to my line chart and my choropleth. This is working really well for the line chart, and I now have a tooltip showing lots of information about each point.

For my choropleth, however, the transition to using reduce instead of reduceSum has really messed up my data. For example:

1. The value getting passed to the tooltip isn't the data I would expect, and I have no idea where the calculation is coming from (it almost seems like it's from the SVG path, or even the color accessor?)
2. As I toggle between different renderings of the choropleth, my choropleth changes, but the value on the tooltip stays exactly the same
3. The initial render of the choropleth is showing a fully blue map, so it seems like the initial value might be incorrect, anyway.

I'm trying to understand how I can identify the data point that's coming from the group, use that to render the choropleth based on a specific value (total_sampled_sales) and then pass that data to the tooltip so that each state's value and metadata can be displayed.

Also, any tips for debugging this type of issue would be greatly appreciated. As you may be able to see from my console.logs, I'm having a hard time tracing the data through to the tooltip. This is presumably the problem block:

```
us1Chart.customUpdate = () => {
        us1Chart.colorDomain(generateScale(returnGroup()))
        us1Chart.group(returnGroup())
      }
      us1Chart.width(us1Width)
        .height(us1Height)
        .dimension(stateRegion)
        .group(returnGroup())
        .colors(d3.scaleQuantize().range(colorScales.blue))
        .colorDomain(generateScale(returnGroup()))
        .colorAccessor(d => {
          // console.log('colorAccessor:', d)
          return d ? d : 0
        })
        .overlayGeoJson(statesJson.features, "state", d => {
          // console.log(`geojson`, d, d.properties.name)
          return d.properties.name
        })
        .projection(d3.geoAlbersUsa()
          .scale(Math.min(getWidth('us1-chart') * 2.5, getHeight('us1-chart') * 1.7))
          .translate([getWidth('us1-chart') / 2.5, getHeight('us1-chart') / 2.5])
        )
        .valueAccessor(kv => {
          // console.log(kv.value)
          if (kv.value !== undefined) return kv.value
        })
        .renderTitle(false)
        .on('pretransition', (chart) => {
          chart.selectAll('path')
            .call(mapTip)
            .on('mouseover.mapTip', mapTip.show)
            .on('mouseout.mapTip', mapTip.hide);
        })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ayyrickay/f1vLwhmq/19/

Note that the data's a little wonky because I removed half of the records just for size constraints

Comment: You're not imagining it, the "wrong" data is bound: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1268 Hope to find some time tomo to dig up if anyone found a workaround.. If not, your best bet might be to keep your own mapping of map keys to whatever data you want to use (or just linear search the `group.all()` for the data you need, which shouldn't be a perf problem for a tooltip). Yep, it's annoying.

Comment: Whew, good to know I'm not crazy. Might set up that map, but I'll probably just do the linear search (it's only 50 records because it's US states, so really shouldn't be a problem.)

Comment: Was not able to find the previous discussion of this, unless I somehow remembered [an unanswered question from 2014](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/dc-js-user-group/choropleth%7Csort:date/dc-js-user-group/8FYcZ6jVtTQ/2lz0hNUdfLYJ)  :-p The linear search should be fine, just inconvenient. I am certain this chart could be designed better, but maybe there is something I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the data binding with choropleths, I'm now using the data that's passed through (specifically, the US State that was selected) and then identifying the data point in the crossfilter group:

```
const selectedState = returnGroup().all().filter(item => item.key === d.properties.name)[0]
```

So I have a returnGroup method that selects the correct choropleth group (based on some app state), gets the list, and then I filter to see which item matches the name property passed to the tooltip. Because filter returns an array, I'm just being optimistic that it'll filter to one item and then use that item. Then I have access to the full data point, and can render it in the tooltip accordingly. Not elegant, but it works.